# How to evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}t^\alpha\mathrm{e}^{-t(1+\mathrm{j}\omega)}\mathrm{d}t$ for $\alpha>-1$ and $\omega>0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform

How to evaluate the integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty}t^\alpha\mathrm{e}^{-t(1+\mathrm{j}\omega)}\mathrm{d}t$$ for $\alpha>-1$, $\mathrm{j}^2=-1$, and $\omega>0$?

I think it should be equal to $\frac{1}{(1+\mathrm{j}\omega)^{\alpha+1}}\Gamma(\alpha+1)$ with $\Gamma$ the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) defined as $$\Gamma(\alpha+1)=\int_0^{\infty}t^\alpha\mathrm{e}^{-t}\mathrm{d}t.$$ How to show this? Does someone know a reference?

Comment: Hint: fix $\alpha$ and call your integral $f(\omega)$. Check $f(0)=\Gamma(\alpha+1)$, and use integration by parts to prove $f'(\omega)=-\frac{(\alpha+1)j}{1+j\omega}f(\omega)$. Hence show $f(\omega)=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}{(1+j\omega)^{\alpha+1}}$.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty t^\alpha e^{-t(1+j\omega)}\mathrm dt &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-j \omega)^k}{k!}\underbrace{\int_{0}^\infty t^{\alpha + k}e^{-t}\mathrm dt}_{=\Gamma(\alpha + k + 1)}\\
&=   \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-j \omega)^k}{k!}(\alpha+k)(\alpha + k - 1)\cdots(\alpha+1)\Gamma(\alpha + 1)\\
&= \Gamma \left(\alpha + 1\right) \underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(\alpha + 1) \cdots (\alpha + k)}{k!} (-j\omega)^k}_{=\frac{1}{(1-(-j\omega))^{\alpha+1}}}\\
&= \frac{\Gamma (\alpha + 1)}{(1+j\omega)^{\alpha + 1}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
$$I=\int t^\alpha\, e^{-t(1+i\omega)}\,{d}t$$
$$t(1+i\omega)=x \implies I=\frac 1 {(1+i \omega )^{\alpha +1} }\int x^\alpha \,e^{-x}\,dx$$

Comment: while the integration for $t$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$ the integration interval for $x$ is complex. I am not sure that this change of coordinate suffices without any arguments about the complex integration ?

Comment: @TooManyQuestionsInLife. I gave the antiderivative. Go back to $t$ and use the bounds